# Porque JSON não é considerado uma linguagem de marcação? E porque XML é?

Tags: json, xml

Estava pesquisando as diferenças entre JSON e XML então li que XML é uma linguagem de marcação mas não li nada a respeito sobre JSON.

Answer (score 5):

Nem sempre esse tipo de categorização é tão rígida, mas na minha opinião seria forçar a barra querer definir JSON como uma linguagem de marcação.

Não consigo imaginar pegar um documento arbitrário e "marcá-lo" usando JSON. É até possível, em teoria. Afinal, tanto XML quanto HTML foram criados para serem interpretados como uma árvore, e JSON organiza as coisas em árvore. Mas repare que já é um grau de abstração acima. Um documento marcado com XML é relativamente legível por humanos antes de ser transformado em árvore. HTML é mais legível ainda. Já JSON não é tão legível.

Vamos tomar como exemplo um trecho bem simples de HTML:

```html
texto <strong>texto destacado</strong> texto
```

O jeito mais simples que consigo imaginar isso em JSON seria:

```js
{
  txt: 'texto ',
  strong: 'texto destacado',
  txt: ' texto'
}
```

Isso é relativamente legível, mas claramente menos que o original. Já o HTML seria muito mais próximo do original. Fora isso, em JSON não há garantia quanto à ordem das chaves de um objeto. Então, a representação acima não é confiável. Seria necessário algo ainda mais complexo, como:

```js
[
  { type: 'text', value: 'texto ' },
  { type: 'strong', value: 'texto destacado' },
  { type: 'text', value: ' texto' }
]
```

Minha conclusão: seria até possível considerar formalmente JSON como uma linguagem de marcação. JSON foi criado com um objetivo um pouco distinto (com mais foco em troca entre sistemas do que na legibilidade, apesar de ser relativamente legível), e por isso não é a solução mais simples para os casos de uso de linguagens de marcação – cujo exemplo mais conhecido é o próprio HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**Traduzido de**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647722/is-json-a-markup-language-like-xml

Do [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language):

> Uma linguagem de marcação (documento) é um sistema moderno para anotar um documento de forma que é sinteticamente distinguível do texto. A idéia e a terminologia evoluíram a partir da "marcação" de manuscritos de papel, ou seja, as instruções de revisão por editores, tradicionalmente escritas com um lápis azul em manuscritos de autores.
>   Então não. JSON não é uma linguagem de marcação.

Para esse assunto, nem o XML. A Wikipedia descreve isso como "uma linguagem meta markup", pois fornece uma base para a criação de linguagens de marcação.

O JSON é como XML, pois é usado para estruturar dados em um formato de texto e é comumente usado para trocar dados pela Internet.